# (MySql) I wonder if partitioning table or database backup via query affects the performance of other activities?

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

Let say that's a table named **orders**, having almost 10millions of data coming in daily. There will be a schedule to split the table accordingly at 0000hrs.

May I know is this schedule going to affect the performance of ***API to retrieve data, insert & update data***?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

120 Inserts/second is about the max that HDD drives can handle.  (SSD can handle much more.)

Meanwhile, a backup is doing lots of reads to fetch the data and, in the dump is stored on the same machine, lots of disk writes.

ALTER TABLE (or whatever you mean by "split the table") to change the partitioning may do a lot of I/O.  Please provide details.  If your SQL is I/O-bound, I may have a much more efficient approach.

Selects will also be slowed down simply because of other things going on.

There are many techniques for speeding up Inserts; we should discuss that, too.  Please describe your Insert mechanism -- one row per "order"?  multiple tables touched per order?  all orders go through one client?  batch inserts?  Etc, etc.